# $\frac{h(x)}{x} \to 0$ as $\lvert x \rvert \to \infty$ implies $\frac{h(y)}{x}$ being bounded when $\lvert x \rvert \geq \max\{1, \lvert y \rvert\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The question is as in the title. Let $h$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that

If $\frac{h(x)}{x} \to 0$ as $\lvert x \rvert \to \infty$. Then, is it true that the two-varaible function
\begin{equation}
\frac{h(y)}{x}
\end{equation}
is bounded in the region $\{(x,y) \mid 1 \leq \lvert x \rvert \text{ and } \lvert y \rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert  \}$?

This is extremely confusing for me and I cannot figure out correctly.. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- On the region $|y|\le1\le|x|,$
  $$\left|\frac{h(y)}x\right|\le|h(y)|
  $$
  is bounded since $h$ is continuous on $[-1,1].$
- On the region $1\le|y|\le|x|,$
  $$\left|\frac{h(y)}x\right|\le\left|\frac{h(y)}y\right|
  $$
  is bounded because $y\mapsto\frac{h(y)}y$ is continuous on $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,+\infty)$ and has limit $0$ as $y\to\pm\infty.$

So: yes, $\frac{h(y)}x$ is bounded on the union $\lvert x \rvert \geq \max(1, \lvert y \rvert)$ of these two regions.